# How to restart server remotely and be sure that it's up

Tags: windows, powershell, server, powershell-3.0

I have a simple code with restart server remotely. I'm using the Invoke Command to execute the script block on one server from another one. Question is **how to restart this server and be sure that after the restart it's up**?

I know that invoke command opens the session, but after restart it will be closed. How to bypass this issue?

**Code**

```
        try {
        $RestartResult = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $AppServer -ScriptBlock 
        {
            Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source "Powershell restart script" –EntryType Information –Message "Server restart initiated"
            Restart-Computer -Wait -For WMI -ea Stop -Delay 30
        }
    }
    catch { 
        # Get the exception message.
        $RestartResult = $_.Exception.Message 
    }

    if ($error) {
        Write-Log ERROR -Message $RestartResult
    }
    else {
        Write-Log INFO -Message 'Host $AppServer has been restarted'
    }
```

Comment: Once your script has executed a restart, you could have another try{}catch{} that attempts to reconnect - if it's successful then you know the server is back up.

Comment: Depends on what "is up" means. Sometimes ping is enough. Sometimes you have to be sure some services running...

Comment: I just want to check if I can establish powershell session on this host, let's say I would like to try to perform something like this on $hostname server:

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock { 1 }

if it will be inposible I'd like to try 2 times more until it's possible or counter for attempts shows 3

Answer (score 0):

You may check the uptime using these code to check if your server was just restarted

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
```

Reference link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/27/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I issue the restart [Restart-Server.ps1](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/master/Source/Server/Helpers/Restart-Server.ps1) and this is how I internally test for it's uptime
[Test-Server.ps1](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/master/Source/Server/Helpers/Test-Server.ps1) to block the execution until it's ready. Not that I actually check that powershell remoting is possible which guarantees me that the server's OS is more than simply booted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName <ConmputerName> -Wait
```

will reboot and waits for PowerShell default endpoint on remote host to come up.